# Direction of $g$ acceleration ball projection

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, kinematics, acceleration, projectile

Why is the answer A? Because I thought it's C, because g acts downward and since the ball is moving downwards towards N, acceleration should be "g" and not "-g" as it was when it was being thrown up at L. Can someone please explain?

[image]

Comment: "...as it was when it was being thrown up at L."  You should read position L as a point immediately after the ball has been released and not about the acceleration from the throw.

Comment: Speed is not a vector quantity so the sign is unchanged; acceleration is, and it is always directed downwards, it does not depend on the direction of motion

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It says right there in the beginning of the sentence  "vectors directed upwards are taken as positive". Still you must look at the speed of the ball" it has a vertical component and an horizontal one, the vertical component is being affected negatively by g, it is slowed by g therefore the negative sign

Comment: Speed has no components. It is the magnitude of the velocity

Comment: Sorry, i see, what i meant was velocity, but the word did not come to me, english isnt my first language

Comment: Still your answer is wrong in the concept. The minus sign in the acceleration does not come from the fact that it slows things because in general *it doesn't*: when the ball is going down, gravity actually speeds it up! The minus sign is due to the downward direction of the vector **g**